# Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

How can I solve this error?

I tried the following:

1. rm ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
2. `TOOLCHAINS=com.apple.dt.toolchain.Swift_3_0_2`
3. `carthage update --no-use-binaries --platform iOS`
4. Xcode's version try to change 8.3.0 -> 8.2.1)

but these are not helpful.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I can't build this xcodeProject. it always fails for the error

Answer (score -1):

Find the Carthage module owner on Github and either ask the owner to update it, or fork it and do it yourself.